# Can't run facebook login in localhost use Laravel

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, api

I want to login to facebook with localhost use laravel for testing my app.
But facebook api does not know my local domain.

1. I start my app on local use `php artisan serve`. When I enter in the browser `http://127.0.0.1:8000` or `http://localhost:8000/login` - my application run successfully.
2. On facebook admin page my app i fill in the required fields.
   [image]
3. But when I logging, I get responce on facebook page `Unable to load URL: The domain of this URL is not part of the application's domain.`

Please tell me what I do wrong! Thank you!

Comment: I use ubuntu 16.04 and apache2

Comment: @taras-bezdushnuy Give localhost:8000 in place of localhost in App Domains and then try

Comment: I paste `http://localhost:8000/` on `App Domains` input but after saving changes and refresh page he is back again to `localhost`. (I think facebook parse this value)

Comment: @taras-bezdushnuy In Facebook Login Settings, enter your URL in Valid OAuth redirect URIs field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Facebook Login Settings, enter URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000` in `Valid OAuth redirect URIs` field as shown below.

[image]

Hope it will work fine then!